# How to switch between shell windows in dwm window manager?

Tags: window-manager, dwm

I read that tutorial on their page, can't find nothing about switching between uxterm shells. Using mouse is too much distraction.

Comment: What Operating system? What window manager? Please provide specific software names and versions.

Comment: freebsd9 (what's the difference??), window manager is DWM, if you not familiar with this you won't know unless you'll read a source code

Comment: `dwm.exe` is the name of the Windows *Desktop Window Manager*, but I had a hunch that this wasn't what you were talking about, so I asked. In general it's always good to know what OS and product/software versions are involved.

Comment: sorry i had to mention this is from suckless.org anyway i found an answer will post tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should've been reading some man pages before asking:
http://pl.digipedia.org/man/doc/view/dwm.1/

```
Mod1-j
Focus next window.
Mod1-k
Focus previous window.
```